# spring security method level authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I face a `403 - Access denied` error every time I try hitting this secured method. I can hit all other methods except this secured one. If it matters, I am using H2 DB.

This is the first time I am trying `spring security`. So forgive me for any simple mistakes

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        if (productService.addProduct(product)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("newly added " + product.getName(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Could not add product " + product.getName(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

My Spring configuration class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String authoritiesQuery = "SELECT USERNAME, ROLE FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME = ?";
    private static final String usersQuery = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, 1 as enabled FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME = ?";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(authoritiesQuery)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/addProduct").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
}
```

My H2 DB entries are:

```
MERGE INTO TBLUSERS VALUES ('Abhi', '$2a$10$5uSoNE.xI.0Pe4uoy1Pd/ushJPh0O32Sa6W/CybjBp9FrytEuPGvq', 'ROLE_USER');
MERGE INTO TBLUSERS VALUES ('Abhishek', '$2a$10$5uSoNE.xI.0Pe4uoy1Pd/ushJPh0O32Sa6W/CybjBp9FrytEuPGvq', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
MERGE INTO TBLUSERS VALUES ('Abhishek', '$2a$10$5uSoNE.xI.0Pe4uoy1Pd/ushJPh0O32Sa6W/CybjBp9FrytEuPGvq', 'ROLE_USER');
```

Comment: @hunt3r: I am trying the request from rest-client (postman). I add the credentials there. And I guess, Since I get 403 error already, I do not need the login form

Comment: How you do you call the API ?

Comment: @chaoluo using a rest client. I am using postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database table `TBLUSERS` contains two users with username `Abhishek`. Apparently the last one with authority `ROLE_USER` is used. But the URL `/addProduct` is only accessible for users with authority `ROLE_ADMIN`. Hence, you get a 403 error message.

If you want to have users with multiple authorities, you have to change your database schema, see for example [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#user-schema):

> **15.1.1 User Schema**
>
> The standard JDBC implementation of the `UserDetailsService` (`JdbcDaoImpl`) requires tables to load the password, account status (enabled or disabled) and a list of authorities (roles) for the user. You will need to adjust this schema to match the database dialect you are using.
>
> ```sql
> create table users(
>     username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
>     password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
>     enabled boolean not null
> );
>
> create table authorities (
>     username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
>     authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
>     constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username)
> );
> create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
> ```